# Retrieve posts by custom field with WP-REST-API in Javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, wp-api

What is the right URL to retrieve posts by meta_query with the WP-REST-API?

The custom field I want to use can contain multiple values, I tried this for custom field which only can contain a single value and this works.

wp-json/posts?format=json&filter[meta_key]=content_type&filter[meta_value]=2

But I can't get it work with a custom field which can contain multiple values (array/object). Anyone?

Comment: I've added these lines of code to accept meta_key & meta_value as parameters in GET request:

add_filter( 'json_query_vars', 'slug_allow_meta' );
function slug_allow_meta( $valid_vars ) {
    $valid_vars = array_merge( $valid_vars, array( 'meta_key', 'meta_value' ) );
    return $valid_vars;
}

But without any positive result though..

Comment: It's working now with the un-official json-api. Based on this thread: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/147723/how-do-you-get-posts-by-meta-query-using-the-json-api-plugin But I really want to use the official WP-REST-API. Hint: The multiple value meta_key contains a serialized array.

Comment: Ok I solved it with the official WP-REST-API.

See:
http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/169408/wp-json-rest-api-ryan-mccue-how-to-query-posts-with-specific-meta-data-with-a

Answer (score 0):

You need the [ACF to REST API](https://github.com/airesvsg/acf-to-rest-api) plugin. In addition to that, you need to make a few customizations such as:

```
add_filter( 'rest_{type}_query', function( $args ) {
    $args['meta_query'] = array(
        array(
            'key'   => 'my_field',
            'value' => esc_sql( $_GET['my_field'] ),
        )
    );

    return $args;
} );
```

See https://github.com/airesvsg/acf-to-rest-api/issues/122#issuecomment-291913932